# MVC with Razor creating drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu

I have the follwing code, I m able to create a drop down list but when I submit, I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception. `News` class has `Category` and Category class have Id, Name, Order.

How can I fix this?

My view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.News.Category.Id, Model.Categories, "Select One")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.News.Category)
 </div>
```

The view model:

```
public class NewsViewModel
{
    public string SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public News News { set; get; }
}
```

And the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewsViewModel newsViewModel)
{
    try
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {

                session.Save(newsViewModel.News);
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I m getting the exception while saving the model `session.Save(newsViewModel.News);`

Comment: where in your code are you getting this error?

Comment: while I m saving the model. session.Save(newsViewModel.News);

Comment: but you didn't pass this object in the session to the View method. Or you didn't use the sessioned model object in the view code.

Comment: Is your dropdown being populated with values on your get request? if yes, on submit, is the viewModel's m.News.Category.Id property is set with the id of the value you've selected in the dropdown? if yes, then its not the problem with the dropdown...it is something to do with the NHibernate session that you are using...try something like (News)session.Save(newsViewModel.News); this...

Comment: +1 to counter the UNNECESSARY -1 on this question... :)

Comment: @DarthVader any luck? I'm just curious to know whats causing the issue...

Comment: @NiK yeah I just got it working and yes you were right. wanna write an answer so I can mark.

Comment: @DarthVader great, I have posted an answer with the same comment, you may tick it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your dropdown being populated with values on your get request?

if yes, on submit, is the viewModel's m.News.Category.Id property is set with the id of the value you've selected in the dropdown?

if yes, then its not the problem with the dropdown...it is something to do with the NHibernate session that you are using...try something like (News)session.Save(newsViewModel.News);

Answer (score 0):

Where do you create the model object? You use Model.Categories in the view, but you don't pass the model object to the view. You should pass the model object as the first parameter of the View method:

```
    ...
    catch
    {
        return View(/* here, there must be a model object */);
    }
```

Something like that:

```
    ...
    catch
    {
        var model = new NewsViewModel();
        return View(model);
        ... or ...
        return View(session.Load<NewsViewModel>(....));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public int? SelectedId { get; set; }

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.Categories, "--Select One--")

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewsViewModel newsViewModel)
{
    if(ModelState.isValid())
    {
    try
    {
        using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                newsViewModel.News.Category.Id = newsViewModel.SelectedId.Value;
                session.Save(newsViewModel.News); 
                tx.Commit();
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont have problem getting the Category object though. It does come through.

Comment: @DarthVader - Not sure how you have a problem with the dropdown then, perhaps you can post in an edit the exception you are getting with more details on the error and whatnot.